# cgexec not inheriting LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: environment-variables, cgroup

My `/etc/cgconfig.conf` file consists of

```
mount {
        cpuset  = /cgroup/cpuset;
        cpu     = /cgroup/cpu;
        cpuacct = /cgroup/cpuacct;
        memory  = /cgroup/memory;
        devices = /cgroup/devices;
        freezer = /cgroup/freezer;
        net_cls = /cgroup/net_cls;
        blkio   = /cgroup/blkio;
}

# make sure this cgroup cannot run more than 100%
group proc1 {
        perm {
                task {
                        uid = jmichael;
                        gid = hpcfadmins;
                } admin {
                        uid = jmichael;
                        gid = hpcfadmins;
                }
        }
        cpu {
                cpu.cfs_quota_us = "1000000";
                cpu.cfs_period_us = "1000000";
        }
}

group proc2 {
        cpu {
                cpu.cfs_quota_us = "2000000";
                cpu.cfs_period_us = "1000000";
        }
}
```

and I noticed that when running `cgexec -g cpu:proc1 myCode.sh` (which contains a binary compiled with a specific version of `gcc`) that is was complaining about libraries. Upon further investigation I find that `env` gives me different results than `cgexec -g cpu:proc1 env`. Specifically, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not included in the output of the `cgexec` version.

How do I get `cgexec` to inherit my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

As a simple test, note the results of the following commands:

```
$ env | grep 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' | sed 's/=.*//'
LD_LIBRARY_PATH
$ cgexec -g cpu:proc1 env | grep 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' | sed 's/=.*//'
$
```

Comment: Show a reproducible example.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://superuser.com/questions/27376/why-does-my-ld-library-path-get-unset-launching-terminal), `cgexec` is a setuid binary